# MPMoviePlayerController wont play movie on iPhone 3G when in release mode but will in debug mode

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, 3g

OK, I've got a weird one here...
I have an issue with MPMoviePlayerController and playing a m4v movie on an old iphone 3g.

When I connect the device to my mac, and run it through Xcode with the build set to Device|Debug - the **movie plays fine**.

When I change the build to Device|Release, the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is called immediately with an error of "This movie format is not supported" and the movie is not shown.

Running 4.1 on the device, and have 4.1 set as the base SDK.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Did you try MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification and see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is really with your video encoding. Try example video provided in this tutorial:

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

If problem still occurs, let me know.